# eslint no-magic-numbers rule can't ignore checking number elements in array

Tags: eslint

I'm new to eslint. With "no-magic-numbers" rule turned on, declare an array with number literal can't be ignored.eg.
`let array = [1, 2, 3];` I looked up eslint's documentation and can't find a way to ignore this case.So I must turn off "no-magic-numbers" rule,am I right?Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turning of a complete rule to fix one error is not a good idea.

If its just one case you can deactivate this rule for just one line like:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-magic-numbers
let array = [1, 2, 3];
```

If you don't like the idea of that rule in general you off course can turn it off completely. Have a look at the documentation to get a better overview: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-magic-numbers

Comment: Turning off the rule each time you get to use array indexes is not an appropriate way to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess OP is no longer in need for this information, but as this thread showed up in my google result, I feel it is still used.

The proper way to deal with this problem is not to disable the rule each time you need to use an array index, but rather to use rule's options to allow array indexes.

As [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-magic-numbers#ignorearrayindexes) states it, you would need to find where this rule is declared and modify the entry as following

```
"no-magic-numbers": ["error", { "ignoreArrayIndexes": true }]
```

Edit : as pointed out, OP's problem relates to array value and not indexes.

The only solution I found is to define those arrays as constant outside of the component / service using them.

Comment: This does not fix the problem the OP has.

Comment: Indeed I read that too fast. Editing my answer

Answer (score -2):

It's a broken and useless ESLint rule. I suggest to disable it completely.

Comment: Please add more context and reasons explaining why this is the case. Otherwise it could be considered opinion-based and may potentially be deleted.

Comment: Check github issues